# Write a function in GAP that returns the elements in the coset gH as a list.

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap

Task is to write a $function$ in GAP which takes as input a group $G$, an element $g∈G$ and a subgroup $H≤G$, and returns the elements in the coset $gH$ as a list. 
I am new to this software program and as far I understand code should look following:

```
function:=function(G,g,H)

local list, ...;

... (main code);

return list;

end;
```

My question is to how to write the main code?

Comment: Is https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/ of any help - in particular episode 1 about finding information in the help system, and episode 3 about functions?

Comment: GAP is a language with a certain degree of contortion when writing code. It may be a good idea to switch directly to sage, www.sagemath.org, which provides a bridge to gap, and to many other possible CAS (computer algebra systems). In sage we have a beautiful way to address and inspect objects, so that programming is no longer an adventure. Regarding a middle and/or long term profit, i would immediately switch to sage.

Comment: @dan_fulea. It may be a good idea. It also may be a horrible idea, adding another layer of complication. Why not advocate that cats are more beatiful than dogs, or vice versa?

Comment: GAP has right cosets as their own objects, and you can create them as product of subgroup times element, and then ask for the elements, E.g. `Elements(S*elm);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (universally recognized as beautiful and highly elegant) programming environment of GAP contains functions that make it easy to apply . Thus, to get the elements of a left coset, I would use

```
left_coset_elms:=function(g,H)
local list;
  list:=AsList(H);
  list:=List(list,x->g*x);
  return list;
end;
```

Note that there is no need to specify the whole group as extra argument.

It might be useful to sort the list of coset elements, to make comparison easier. For this, simply add a line `Sort(list);` befor the `return` command.